# Date conversion - seconds to hour/minutes/seconds

Tags: c#, .net, date

considering that each shipment takes two minutes and I have 500 users to send, how to calculate the estimated time?

I tried this:

```
var seconds = 120; //2minutes
var users = 500;
int t = 0;
int i = 0;

while(i <= users)
{
 i++;
t += seconds;
}
```

how I convert `t` to something like: `xxx` hours and `yyy` minutes and `zzz` seconds?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider using `Timespan` , then you can use Hour, Minutes and seconds component of the instance

Comment: Why are you looping?  Wouldn't 120 * 500 be the equivalent?

Comment: why are you using t as int? You could have used DateTime itself? Start with DateTime.now and then take DateTime.now sample after it finishes. Then subtract them and take elapsed in milliseconds or what ever is needed. Hope this is what your asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TimeSpan  duration = Timespan.FromSeconds(t);
```

Convert your seconds to a timespan object, and you will get all the extra information for free

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for something like this

you may intialize it like this

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
```

and addition in this fashion

```
ts.Add(new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0));
```

And your final format can be achieved as this

```
string.Format("{0} Hours {1} minutes {2} seconds", ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds);
```

In case you can use a timer or calculate the entire duration then use that to initialize the timespan. Please modify as you need or add further details to your question